# Mongodb $project for calculate if id belong

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have a model of broadcasting notifications, keeping when the user read one of them to display a different state.

We keep this readBy as an array of subdocuments.

I was wondering if there is a way to using aggregate or a map-reduce with mongoosejs is it posible to calculate if the user is one of the readers to return a true instead of all the readers array.

```
{_id: "1", title: "A", readBy:["User1","User2"] }
{_id: "2", title: "B", readBy:["User1"] }
{_id: "3", title: "C", readBy:["User2"] }
```

If the **User1** try to recover the list of documents, what I want to return is something like:

```
{_id: "1", title: "A", read: true }
{_id: "2", title: "B", read: true }
{_id: "3", title: "C", read: false }
```

Obviously I could perform a post-process in the server, but I was wondering if there is a way to calculate directly with mongodb.

Another option is to filter the content of the readBy array with just the User1, something like:

```
{_id: "1", title: "A", readBy: ["User1"] }
{_id: "2", title: "B", readBy: ["User1"] }
{_id: "3", title: "C", readBy: [] }
```

Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mongodb version 3.4+ then you can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#exp._S_in) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { _id:1, title:1, read: {$in:["User1", "$readBy"]} }}
])
```

For mongodb version 3.2+ you can achieve your second option via [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id:1, 
            title:1, 
            readBy: { 
                $filter: {
                    input: "$readBy",
                    as: "user",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$user", "User1"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks Sergei, finally I decided to go using find and reducing the readBy list with elemMatch. I changed the structure of readby from strings array to subdocuments array for that. But your solutions works. So my OK for you! THANK YOU!